# Right inverse is also left inverse for nonsquare matrices?

Tags: matrices

If $m≠n$ and we have the matrices $A$ $(m\times{n})$, $B$  $(n\times{m})$ and $C$  $(n\times{m})$ such that $AB=I(m\times{m})$ and $CA=I(n\times{n})$, does $B=C$?

I know the proof that it is true if we are talking about square matrices, but it doesn't help in this case.

Comment: Nice hint. It just became clear

Comment: @AlexandreTourinho What proof do you know in the square case that doesn't work here?

Comment: @DanielMroz  If $B$ and $C$ existed, then your hint would work.  The problem is that they **do not exist**.

Comment: @Batominovski Ugh, that's what I get for commenting without thinking. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

The conditions on your matrices cannot be satisfied.  If $m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $m\neq n$, then there does not exist an $m$-by-$n$ matrix $A$  (over any base field $\mathbb{K}$), along with two $n$-by-$m$ matrices $B$ and $C$, such that $AB=I_{m\times m}$ and $CA=I_{n\times n}$.  Here, $I_{k\times k}$ is the $k$-by-$k$ identity matrix.

To show this, we may assume without loss of generality that $m<n$ (otherwise, replace $A$ by $A^\top$, $B$ by $C^\top$, and $C$ by $B^\top$).  Suppose on the contrary that such $A$, $B$, and $C$ exist.  Since $A$ is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix, the rank of $A$ is at most $m$.  Therefore, as the column space of $CA$ is a subset of the column space of $A$, the rank of $CA$ is at most $m$.  This contradicts the assumption that $CA=I_{n\times n}$, as $I_{n\times n}$ is of rank $n>m$.

Comment: I actually dont't know ranks very well. So what you are saying is that if $B$ and $C$ existed, then $B=C$ would be true, but the fact is that there can exist $B$ such that $AB=I$ but that would implie the inexistence of $C$ or that there can't exist $B$ at all? Is there an easier way I can comprehend the proof?

Comment: Correct!  For a non-square matrix $A$, at most one of these two statements can be true (that is, both of them cannot happen at the same time, but both of them may also fail at the same time): (1) $A$ has a right inverse $B$; (2) $A$ has a left inverse $C$.  I do not know how else to explain the proof, but rank is a very useful concept that you should learn.